# ${fn:escapeXml(var)} does not display the value of var

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I am following [this](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore) tutorial of google appengine. I have a jsp file where I use `${fn:escapeXml(var)}` to put the value of String variable `var` in the html code that will be generated. However, the resultant html code does not put anything at that place. I confirmed it using the *view source* option in the chrome.

Following is my jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>

<%@page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Query"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreService"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.DatastoreServiceFactory"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Entity"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.FetchOptions"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.Key"%>
<%@ page import="com.google.appengine.api.datastore.KeyFactory"%>


<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">



<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<% String var = "asd";  %>
    
value of var:"${fn:escapeXml(var)}"
</body>
</html>
```

Following is the html code that appears upon clicking "view source" in chrome:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">



<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>

    
value of var:"" 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scriptlet variable is not available in EL scopes. Try

```
<c:set var="c"><%=var%></c:set>
value of var:"${fn:escapeXml(c)}"
```

Comment: +1 but try to avoid Scriplet.

Comment: @Braj Do you know what is a scriptlet?

Comment: What is this `<%=var%>`

Comment: There are three types of scripting elements: 1.) scriptlet tag `<%...%>` 2.) expression tag `<%=...%>` 3.) declaration tag `<%!...%>`

Comment: I don't understand what is a _scripting element_ and which option(s) are used for scriptlets. Navigating question: how many Java statements a scriptlet can contain?

Comment: I simple term I am talking about any uses of `<% %>` in JSP. that's all. If you love it then no worry just use it. Please have a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) and specially read first line of the answer.

Comment: This is your option 1, but I didn't use it, I've used your option 2. As far as I know JSP it's a JSP expression and not a tag, the tag is `<jsp:expression>`.

Comment: @Braj I now already (about decade) since struts tags has been introduced, all presentation logic moved to tags (nowadays it's moved to html5,css3, and javascript)  and business logic moved to a business layer. But this is not a question about best practices or best framework or best taglib to use instead of scriptlets.

Answer (score 2):

You should [avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) *scriptlets* altogether and use JSTL/EL to prepare this variable as you already using for *function*.

I suggest you to use [JavaServer Pages Standard Tag Library](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnakc.html) or [Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjddd.html) instead of `Scriplet` that is more easy to use and less error prone.

```
<c:set var="value" value="asd"/>    
value of var:"${fn:escapeXml(value)}"
```

you might interested in this one as well

```
<c:out value="value" [escapeXml="{true|false}"] [default="defaultValue"] />
```

Read more

- [Oracle Tutorial - Using JSTL](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSTL3.html)
- [Oracle Tutorial - Expression Language](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html)

Answer (score 0):

In JSP/Java You should use this code:

In JSP/HTML:

```
<c:out value="TR tag </tr> Script Tag <script>alert("hello Rahul")</script>" escapeXml="true" />
```

In Java:

```
import org.springframework.web.util.HtmlUtils;

System.out.println(HtmlUtils.htmlEscape("TR tag </tr> Script Tag <script>alert('hello Rahul')");
```